# Jquery Accordian activate event is not getting fired ,

Tags: jquery

On click of the Horizontal tab , i am creating a Accordion dynamically , and further clicks on Accordian , it must  create child Accordians (Nested Accordians)

This is my complete code ,http://jsfiddle.net/aEL2e/

I have observed that the Accordian Activate event is not being fired

```
$(".accordian").accordion({
  //  activate: function (event, ui) {
    //    setStuff(event, ui);
   // }
 change: function( event, ui ) {
setStuff(event, ui);
   }
});
```

Could anybody please help me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your accordion for element with class `.accordion` has no inner elements so that it may be transformed to an accordion and fire the `activate` event. If you put the activate event in your first accordion it will be fired because it is being transformed to an accordion:

```
$("#daccordion").accordion({
    activate: function (event, ui) {
        alert('accordion activated');
        setStuff(event, ui);
    },
   .
   .
   .
   .
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aEL2e/1/)